# I created a dictionary but keep getting a key error, I have tried alternatives but nothing is working

Tags: python, dictionary, key, keyerror

Below is the code that I have written. I am able to run and print the `Transaction_Dict` but when I try to run the `Coffee = Transaction_Dict['Type']` line, I get an error saying that there is a `KeyError`.

```
CoffeeType = ['Classic','Breakfast Blend','Rev It Up']

Transaction_Dict = {
    'T1': {'Type': 'Classic', 'Total': 37.33},
    'T2': {'Type': 'Rev It Up', 'Total': 45.82},
    'T3': {'Type': 'Breakfast Blend', 'Total': 32.32},
    'T4': {'Type': 'Classic', 'Total': 47.75},
    'T5': {'Type': 'Classic', 'Total': 28.18},
    'T6': {'Type': 'Breakfast Blend', 'Total': 46.94},
    'T7': {'Type': 'Rev It Up', 'Total': 33.89},
    'T8': {'Type': 'Breakfast Blend', 'Total': 26.91},
    'T9': {'Type': 'Breakfast Blend', 'Total': 22.03},
    'T10': {'Type': 'Classic', 'Total': 33.35}}


CT_Dict = {'Classic': 3.50, 'Breakfast Blend': 4.00, 'Rev It Up': 5.00}
Total_Spent = {Type: 0 for Type in CoffeeType}
Total_Weight = 0

for transaction in Transaction_Dict.values():
  Coffee = Transaction_Dict['Type']
  Amount = Transaction_Dict['Total']
  Total_Spent[Coffee] += Amount
  Total_Weight += Amount / CT_Dict[Coffee]
```

This is the output that I am getting:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-3ec8797f18f1> in <cell line: 22>()
     21 
     22 for transaction in Transaction_Dict.values():
---> 23   Coffee = Transaction_Dict['Type']
     24   Amount = Transaction_Dict['Total']
     25   Total_Spent[Coffee] += Amount

KeyError: 'Type'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access the 'Type' and 'Total' keys from the Transaction_Dict dictionary incorrectly inside the loop. You should access these keys from the transaction variable, which represents each transaction in the loop. Here's the corrected code:

```py
CoffeeType = ['Classic', 'Breakfast Blend', 'Rev It Up']

Transaction_Dict = {
    'T1': {'Type': 'Classic', 'Total': 37.33},
    'T2': {'Type': 'Rev It Up', 'Total': 45.82},
    'T3': {'Type': 'Breakfast Blend', 'Total': 32.32},
    'T4': {'Type': 'Classic', 'Total': 47.75},
    'T5': {'Type': 'Classic', 'Total': 28.18},
    'T6': {'Type': 'Breakfast Blend', 'Total': 46.94},
    'T7': {'Type': 'Rev It Up', 'Total': 33.89},
    'T8': {'Type': 'Breakfast Blend', 'Total': 26.91},
    'T9': {'Type': 'Breakfast Blend', 'Total': 22.03},
    'T10': {'Type': 'Classic', 'Total': 33.35}
}

CT_Dict = {'Classic': 3.50, 'Breakfast Blend': 4.00, 'Rev It Up': 5.00}
Total_Spent = {Type: 0 for Type in CoffeeType}
Total_Weight = 0

for transaction in Transaction_Dict.values():
    Coffee = transaction['Type']
    Amount = transaction['Total']
    Total_Spent[Coffee] += Amount
    Total_Weight += Amount / CT_Dict[Coffee]
```